# Tikz: Multiobjective optimization

Tags: optimization, latex, tikz

I am trying to create the following graph:

[image: mutiobjective optimization]

I am trying with this code, but I am not able to create those regions.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=black!15] plot  %
coordinates {(3.7,0.35) (3.7,3.25) (0.75,0.35)};
\draw [fill=black!30] plot  %
coordinates {(2.75,0.9) (2.75,3.5) (0.75,0.9)};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=north] {$C$};
\draw   (1,0.9) node[anchor=north] {$(C_o,R_r)$}
    (2.75,2.75) node[anchor=west] {$(C_r,R_o)$}
    (3.7,0.35) node[anchor=west] {$(C_i,R_i)$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[anchor=east] {$R$};
\draw[thick,->] (3.7,0.35) -- (1,0.9);
\draw[thick,->] (3.7,0.35) -- (2.75,2.75);
\draw [gray] (2.75,2.75) arc [radius=1.52, start angle=111.6, end angle= 
168.49];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much in advance,

Julio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a raw sketch:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=north] {$C$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[anchor=east] {$R$};
\fill [gray!15] plot coordinates {(3.7,0.35) (3.2,3.2) (0.5,0.8)};
\fill [gray!15] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2.7,1.35) (3.2,3.2) (1.5,2.6) (0.5,0.8)};
\fill [gray!30] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(3.4,0.65) (2.7,2.9) (2,2.6) (1.2,1.75) (1,0.9)};
\filldraw (3.7,0.35) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (2.75,2.75) circle (1.5pt);
\filldraw (1,0.9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw  (1,0.9) node[anchor=north] {$(C_o,R_r)$}
(2.75,2.75) node[anchor=west] {$(C_r,R_o)$}
(3.7,0.35) node[anchor=west] {$(C_i,R_i)$};
\draw[thick,->] (3.7,0.35) -- (1,0.9);
\draw[thick,->] (3.7,0.35) -- (2.75,2.75);
\draw[dashed] (1,0.9) arc [radius=2.2, start angle=171.6, end angle=101];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where I used `\fill [gray!30]` for the darker region and two `\fill [gray!15]` for the lighter one (two, to better sketch both straight and curve edges).

The three points `(1,0.9)`, `(3.7,0.35)` and `(2.75,2.75)` are from your code, the other ones should be more carefully sketched on paper before typing the code.